# update with csv file using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, file-handling

I have to update the database with the CSV files. Consider the database table looks like this:
[image: database table]

The CSV file data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the CSV file data some data modified and some new records are added and what I supposed to do is to update only the data which is modified or some new records which are added.

In Table2 the first record of col2 is modified.. I need to update only the first record of col2(i.e, AA) but not the whole records of col2.

I could do this by hardcoding but I don't want to do it by hardcoding as I need to do this with 2000 tables.

Can anyone suggest me the steps to approach my goal.

Here is my code snippet..

```
df = pd.read_csv('F:\\filename.csv', sep=",", header=0, dtype=str)

sql_query2 = engine.execute('''
                               SELECT
                               *
                               FROM ttcmcs023111temp
                               ''')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(sql_query2)
df.update(df2)
```

Comment: FYI, some basic formatting and grammar goes a long way when posting a question. Please do ensure you use basic things, for example capitalisation of words at the start of your sentence are a most.

Comment: What code have you written so far? Post the code snippet.

Comment: okay.. can you give me any suggestions to my question

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: Edit your question and include the code.

Comment: I have included the code @VishalA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have data similar to you, I used my own DB.
The schema of my books table is as follows:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| author | char(30)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And the table looks like this:

```
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| id | name               | author           |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Origin             | Dan Brown        |
|  2 | River God          | Wilbur Smith     |
|  3 | Chromosome 6       | Robin Cook       |
|  4 | Where Eagles Dare  | Alistair Maclean |
|  5 | The Seventh Scroll | Dan Brown        |  ### Added wrong entry to prove 
+----+--------------------+------------------+  ### my point
```

So, my approach is to create a new temporary table with the same schema as the books table from the CSV using python.
The code I used is as follows:

```
sql_query = sqlalchemy.text("CREATE TABLE temp (id int primary key, name varchar(30) not null, author varchar(30) not null)")
result = db_connection.execute(sql_query)
csv_df.to_sql('temp', con = db_connection, index = False, if_exists = 'append')
```

Which creates a table like this:

```
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| id | name               | author           |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Origin             | Dan Brown        |
|  2 | River God          | Wilbur Smith     |
|  3 | Chromosome 6       | Robin Cook       |
|  4 | Where Eagles Dare  | Alistair Maclean |
|  5 | The Seventh Scroll | Wilbur Smith     |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
```

Now, you just need to use the `update` in MySQL using `INNER JOIN` to update the values you want to update in your original table. (in my case, 'books').

Here's how you'll do this:

```
statement = '''update books b
inner join temp t
on t.id = b.id
set b.name = t.name,
b.author = t.author;
'''
db_connection.execute(statement)
```

This query will update the values in table `books` from the table `temp` that I've created using the CSV.

You can destroy the `temp` table after updating the values.

Comment: Thanks @VishalA and the same thing i need to do with multiples tables like around 2000 tables simultaneously, if you had any solution or clue please share to me .

Comment: If every table has a similar schema, you can perform the actions inside a for loop and destroy the `temp` at the end of every iteration.

Comment: statement = '''update books b
inner join temp t
on t.id = b.id
set b.name = t.name,
b.author = t.author;
''', here is where i feel complicated to put inside a loop as every table has its different column names

Comment: Create a list of column names and pass these values as variables to the SQL query. You can get some idea form here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: let me try as you said

Comment: As i am new to this programming, i am not getting how to do this, can you please help me out in this @VishalA.